# concurrent use of geometry package with watermarks

Tags: margins, geometry, watermark

I'd like to include a graphic as watermark in a document with the `twoside` option and asymmetric page margins adjusted with the `geometry` package. There's a plethora of packages that are suitable for the task, but with a few restrictions:

The `xwatermark` package is simple to use, but I can't specify options for even and odd pages at the same time, so either the watermark appears only on half of the pages or it's page-centered rather than text-centered.
With packages such as `watermark`, I can't exclude the watermark on specific pages, e.g. the title page and certain pages with diagrams.
Lastly, packages like `atbegshi` provide access to `dvi` internals, but I don't have the time to work it all out myself.

So my question is: what is the most elegant way to implement such a flexible watermark? If it is relevant, I'm currently using `LaTeX` with `PSTricks` on Windows 7, but may well switch to `ConTeXt` with `PGF/TikZ` on Linux in the future...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the `watermark` package otherwise works, why can't you use its `\thiswatermark{}` command to place an empty watermark on the pages you don't want to have watermarks on?

Comment: @alan-munn as it turned out, I just messed up the `\put` command--now it works fine. And since its position is relative to the _text_ area, I don't need to distinguish between even and odd pages...

Comment: I suggest closing this question then, since it was based on a miscoding rather than an actual problem with the packages mentioned.

Comment: In *xwatermark* package use two separate calls to `\newwatermark` to specify different options for even and odd pages. A minimal example will be useful here.

Answer (score 3):

You could also go with tikz. Page 170 in the PGF & TIKZ manual shows an example.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [rotate=60,scale=10,text opacity=0.2]
at (current page.center) {Example};
\end{tikzpicture}
```